# jQuery / Javascript - variable as object key

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
currentid = 77;
produktid = 2222;
name = "bla";

$.extend(artikel,{
    currentid:{"produktid":produktid, "name":name}
});


var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(artikel);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

The result in the console is:

```
{"currentid":{"produktid":2222,"name":"bla"}}
```

But is must be:

```
{"77":{"produktid":2222,"name":"bla"}}
```

or

```
{77:{"produktid":2222,"name":"bla"}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use computed property names

```
currentid = 77;
produktid = 2222;
name = "bla";

$.extend(artikel,{
    [currentid]:{"produktid":produktid, "name":name}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to add the property using associative array syntax like this.

```
currentid = 77;
produktid = 2222;
name = "bla";
obj = {};
obj[currentId] = {"produktid": produktid, "name": name};

$.extend(artikel, obj);
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(artikel);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks but guest271314 was faster ^^

Comment: @AnneSchwarz Yeah, if I had seen his answer, I wouldn't have posted mine because his is nicer, but requires ES6 support.